# Libxml Cleaner adds unwanted <p> tag to HTML fragments

Tags: python, parsing, libxml2

I'm trying to sanitize user input to prevent XSS injection using libxml's HTML cleaner. When I input a string like this:

```
Normal text <b>Bold text</b>
```

I get this instead:

```
<p>Normal text <b>Bold text</b></p>
```

I want to get rid of the `<p>` tag that surrounds all of my input.

---

Here is the function that currently does the cleaning:

```
from lxml.html import clean

cleaner = clean.Cleaner(
    scripts = True,
    javascript = True,
    allow_tags = None,
)

def sanitize_html(html):
    return cleaner.clean_html(html)
```

---

On an unrelated note, the above code has one line: `allow_tags = None` where I'm trying to remove all HTML tags. Does libxml have a whitelist feature where I **only** allow certain tags?

Comment: What problem, exactly, is caused by leaving in the `<p>` tags?

Comment: @Karl: I'm passing the cleaned output through Markdown, which will ignore anything within a block-level tag for formatting. It also messes with my other CSS rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All `TEXT` fragments/nodes must be enclosed in some kind of an element. `libxml` will attempt to fix this as best as it can.

```
def sanitize_html(html):
    cleaned_html = cleaner.clean_html(html)
    return re.sub(r'</p>$', '', re.sub(r'^<p>', '', cleaned_html))
```

Caching the compiled regular expressions or finding more efficient ways of doing this is left as an exercise to the viewer. Without re-reviewing libxml2, I think you can get away with a slice:

```
return cleaned_html[3:-4]     # Single slice operation
return cleaned_html[3:][:-4]
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that everything needs to be enclosed, I wasn't aware of that. My solution has actually been to enclose the text in another tag before cleaning.